# Toggle between a formarray controls and another form control is not working in angular?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

Hi I am having an angular 5 issue . Its available in stack blitz here.
https://angular-ivy-jmrzng.stackblitz.io/

The issue is i have an angular 5 form . in the angular form i have a form array control named authorities and another control named censorshipApprover.

```
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
  authorities: this.fb.array([], Validators.required),
  censorshipApprover: ['']
});
```

Both the form array controls and the control named censorshipApprover are displayed as check boxes. The issue when I check the checkbox control in the form array it should uncheck the censorshipapprover control . Also when i check the censorship approver control i would like to un check all the controls in the formarray.
However it is not working. any idea what should i do to achieve this functionality. the following is the logic

```
enum Authority {
  SYSTEM_ADMIN = 'ROLE_SYSTEM_ADMIN',
  GLOBAL_ADMIN = 'ROLE_GLOBAL_ADMIN',
  ACCOUNT_ADMIN = 'ROLE_ACCOUNT_ADMIN',
  ANONYMOUS = 'ROLE_ANONYMOUS',
  CAMPAIGN_MANAGER = 'ROLE_CAMPAIGN_MANAGER',
  TEAM_MEMBER = 'ROLE_TEAM_MEMBER',
  CENSORSHIP_APPROVER = 'ROLE_CENSORSHIP_APPROVER'
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  authorities: Authority[] = [
    Authority.TEAM_MEMBER,
    Authority.CAMPAIGN_MANAGER,
    Authority.ACCOUNT_ADMIN
  ];

 formGroup: FormGroup;
 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}
 
  ngOnInit() {

    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      authorities: this.fb.array([], Validators.required),
      censorshipApprover: ['']
    });

    this.authorities.forEach(e => {
        this.authoritiesArray.push(this.fb.control(false));
    })


    this.authoritiesArray.valueChanges.subscribe(values => {
      this.censorshipApproverControl.setValue(false);
    });

  this.censorshipApproverControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
     if (value) {
          this.authoritiesArray.controls.forEach(control => {
            control.setValue(false);
          });
    }
  });

  }
  get censorshipApproverControl(): FormControl {
    return this.formGroup.get('censorshipApprover') as FormControl;
  }
  get authoritiesArray(): FormArray {
    return this.formGroup.get('authorities') as FormArray;
  }
}
```

the following is the html template

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="formGroup">

  <div *ngFor="let authority of authoritiesArray.controls; let i = index" formArrayName="authorities">
   User-Role-{{ i }} <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i" /> 
  </div>  

  <div> Or </div>

  Censor-Role <input
    formControlName="censorshipApprover"
    type="checkbox"
  />

</form>
```

You can also access the stackblitz at this location
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jmrzng?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

when you play around with the stackblitz you can see i am able to check User-Role-0,User-Role-1 and User-Role-2 and then i check the Censor-Role it will clear the User-Role-0,User-Role-1 and User-Role-2 checkboxes. However when i check the  Censor-Role , it is not getting checked.

How can i achieve it .
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valueschanges of `authorities` always setting the `censorshipApprover` value to false. That's why it is not getting checked. You can do like below, if there is one checkbox checked in `authorities` array, then only change the status of `censorshipApprover`

```
this.authoritiesArray.valueChanges.subscribe(values => {
  if (values.some(val => val === true)) {
    this.censorshipApproverControl.reset();
  }
});

this.censorshipApproverControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  if (value) {
    this.authoritiesArray.reset();
  }
});
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fwtxpy)